# How to change date format in Moment.js?

Tags: reactjs, momentjs

The date format that I get from an API is  `24/09/2020 22:58:58` but i want that to change in `Yesterday at 10:58 PM` in `Moment.js`

PS: i tried but didn't work out

Comment: Please include any code that you've tried so far and didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could display like that using [moment calendar time](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/calendar-time/)

```js
const date = moment("24/09/2020 22:58:58", "DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss").calendar()

console.log(date)
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [Calendar time section on the Moment.js landing page](https://momentjs.com/)

`moment().subtract(1, 'days').calendar();`  will give you for example *Yesterday at 10:58 PM* by subtracting a day from the current time and converting into [calendar time](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/calendar-time/)

This is if you want to get the same time as now but yesterday. If you want to get a specific time, just pass in to  the `moment()` as an argument then convert to `calendar()` like so:

`moment('24/09/2020 22:58:58', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss').calendar()`